# What Version of Ubuntu 12.04 should i use?

Tags: 12.04

I have a AMD 32-bit operating system, should i use the 32 bit or 64 bit download? (the reason i ask is because the 64 bit download is labeled AMD, and the 32 bit is labeled Intel. But mine is both AMD and 32 bit, so im a bit confused on which one to use.) Thanks!

Comment: Please also add the model of the processor and RAM size to your question. The `amd64` label only means that your processor supports a 64-bit archicture (like of AMD or Intel). Another name for `amd64` is `x86-64`, look it up on Wikipedia.

Comment: To clarify, the same is true about the 32-bit Ubuntu image: it's label `i386` (as if Intel only) but it includes other processors which are compatible with it (AMD, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Since your processor is a 32bit CPU you can only run a 32bit system. The fact that it says amd64 or it calls the 32bit version intel does not matter. Ubuntu can support both architectures(AMD and Intel). Use the 32bit version. :)

However I would recommend getting 13.04 if your using it as a desktop environment. Many speed improvements have been implemented in this version.

If you want to check if your CPU is infact a 64bit CPU this is how to do so:

**Windows:**

Open System by clicking the Start button, right-clicking Computer, and then clicking Properties.

Under System, you can view the system type.

**If your computer is running Windows XP, do the following:**

Click Start.

Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.

If you don't see "x64 Edition" listed, then you're running the 32-bit version of Windows XP.

If "x64 Edition" is listed under System, you're running the 64-bit version of Windows XP.

**Ubuntu/linux:**

Type this in the terminal

```
lscpu
```

If the output contains this:

```
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
```

Rather than this:

```
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit
```

You have a 64bit CPU